# Data not being passed on view when returning from controller in ASP.NET MVC using C#

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Below is my AJAX call to the mentioned function. I am loading the full view using window.location :

```
function CheckPrevTrans() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"GetPrevTrans",
        method:"POST",
        data:
        {
            
        },
        success: function(res)
        {
            if (res) {
                window.location = "PrevTransactionsView"
            }
            else{
                alert('There are no previous transactions present. If you think that is not the case, please contact your administrator.')
            }
        },
        fail: 
        {
            
        },
       })
}
```

This is my controller method logic which is being called and returns a view. By the end of this method, the output var has 30 elements in the list(can be verified during debugging) :

```
[HttpPost]
public bool GetPrevTrans()
{
    List<string> output = new List<string>();

    string card_Number = HttpContext.Session.GetString("card_No");
    output = tdvObj.GetPrevTrans(card_Number);

    PrevTransactionsView(output);            

    if (output != null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult PrevTransactionsView(List<string> output)
{
    ViewData["Prev5Trans"] = output;
    return View("PrevTransactionsView");
}
```

And lastly, here is my view that I am returning (`PrevTransactionsView`):

```
@{
    List<string> All_TransList = (List<string>)ViewData["Prev5Trans"];
}

<div>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Transaction ID</th>
        <th>Transaction Date</th>
        <th>Transaction Type</th>
        <th>User ID</th>
        <th>Card ID</th>
        <th>Account Number</th>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        @{                   
             List<string> FirstFive = All_TransList.Take(6).ToList();
             foreach (string transVal in FirstFive)
             {
                  <td>@transVal</td>                         
             }
         }
    </tr>        
    </table>
</div>
```

Before you guys help out, I want the view to be returned as a new page and not a partial view.

And the view is being returned but the javascript code in the view page is not being implemented where I am trying to print the top elements of the list (output) inside the `<td>` tags.

But in the view all I am getting are the `<th>` headings.

How do I make the Javascript code work in this scenario?

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: For starters, why combine AJAX with loading a new page?  The point of AJAX is to *not* load a new page.  Aside from that... There's no data being transferred to that new page.  Just calling `PrevTransactionsView(output);` doesn't do anything.  It executes the method, but ignores the result.  And the navigation to `PrevTransactionsView` is an empty GET request, so `output` won't have anything in it.  It appears what you have here is a combination of several misunderstandings of how ASP.NET MVC (and web applications in general) works.

Comment: Also... *"but the javascript code in the view page is not being implemented"* - Do you mean in the second view shown above?  There is no JavaScript in that.  The problem description implies that the JavaScript shown in the first code snippet is on a previous view, and is working as expected, no?

Comment: hi, Have posted an answer for it. Please check and let me know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Made below changes and it worked!:

calling from .cshtml file:

```
//remov9ing the AJAX call and adding a direct URL call  
function CheckPrevTrans(){
    window.location="PrevTransactionsView"
}
```

Controller Method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult PrevTransactionsView()
    {
        List<string> output = new List<string>();
        string card_Number = HttpContext.Session.GetString("card_No");
        output = tdvObj.GetPrevTrans(card_Number);
        ViewData["Prev5Trans"] = output;
        return View();                      

    }
```